# How to show buttons after uploading picture in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created an html page containing an image and related controls like edit, delete and add buttons. The purpose is when in default you have to show only the plus icon, after uploading an image hide th plus button and show edit and delete button. But now the problem is when hovering the image all controls are showing at the same time and it is difficult to mouse click delete or edit buttons. How to show edit and delete buttons after uploading profile picture in html and also how to show plus icon when there is default picture or there is no picture in the same div. 
Can anyone help me?

[default profile image][1]

[after uploading profile image][2]

Please see the attached image. Can it be done using jquery?

```css
.profile_image {position: relative; padding: 0px 40px; margin-bottom: 40px;}
    .add_new_candidate {margin: 20px 10px;}
    .profile_img_ctrls {position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;}
    .profile_img_ctrls a {background: #8aa2ad; border-radius: 50%; width: 20px;  height: 20px; float: left; text-align: center; color: #fff; margin-right: 15px;}
    .profile_add_picture {width: 30px !important; height: 30px !important; margin-top: -8px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;}
    .add_new_candidate input {margin-top: 45px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;}
    .profile_add_picture input.upload {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 20px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0);}
    .profile_add_picture i {font-size: 20px; padding-top: 5px;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
                        <div class="add_new_candidate profile_image">
                         <div class="col-md-3">
                             <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/user_male2-512.png" >
                                <div class="profile_img_ctrls">
                                 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                                    <a class="profile_add_picture" href="#">
                                     <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                     <input type="file" class="upload" />
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full name" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the question. Maybe if you write it more clearly...

Comment: Including an image in your explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: If you could produce a runnable code snippet it would be much more helpful than an image - some of us are behind corporate proxies and are unable to view images on SO.

Comment: do you use any framework? e.g. Vue, Angular, React ?

Comment: How is an image added?  Is there a CMS?  An AJAX call?   Some front-end JS framework?  Generally you'd hook into that process.  But this question can't be answered without more info.

Comment: This is just plain html. And my first dashboard designing. If u see the attached image u guys will understand.

Answer (score 0):

Just play with css selector. Basically add `defaut-image` class to default image and change this class to `user-image` when user uploaded the image and use the code below

**1. When there is default image**

```css
.profile_img_ctrls a{
    display: none
}
.default-image + .profile_img_ctrls .profile_add_picture {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="add_new_candidate profile_image">
        <div class="col-md-3">
           <img class="img-responsive img-circle defaut-image" src="dist/img/avatar.png" >
           <div class="profile_img_ctrls">
               <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
               <a class="profile_add_picture" href="#">
                   <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                   <input type="file" class="upload" />
               </a>
               <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
           </div>
      </div>
            
      <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full name" >
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**2. When user have change the pic**

```css
.user-image + .profile_img_ctrls a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="add_new_candidate profile_image">
       <div class="col-md-3">
           <img class="img-responsive img-circle user-image" src="dist/img/avatar.png" >
           <div class="profile_img_ctrls">
               <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
               <a class="profile_add_picture" href="#">
                   <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                   <input type="file" class="upload" />
               </a>
               <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
           </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-9">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full name" >
       </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rakesh Soni. Can it be done using jquery? I have modified the question and attached some screenshot. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript check image.
If is default image show Upload button else show edit, del button

My example Code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 showButton(); // check image for show button

 function showButton() {
  var default_image_name = 'anonymous_avatar.png'; // default image name
  var image_now = $('#image-show img').attr('src');
  //default name indexof != -1
  if(image_now.indexOf(default_image_name) != -1 ){
   DefaultImageButton();
  } else {
   ChangeImageButton();
  }
 }

 function DefaultImageButton(){
  $('#BtnUpload').show();
  $('#BtnEdit').hide();
  $('#BtnDel').hide();
 }
 function ChangeImageButton(){
  $('#BtnUpload').hide();
  $('#BtnEdit').show();
  $('#BtnDel').show();
 }
});
```

```css
#BtnEdit, #BtnDel{
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   color: white;
 }
 #BtnEdit{
   background-color:blue;
 }
 #BtnDel{
   background-color:red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="avatar-frame">

  <div id="image-show"><img src="https://jnswire.s3.amazonaws.com/jns-media/ea/05/91552/anonymous_avatar.png"></div>
 <input id="BtnUpload" type="file" accept ="image/*">
 <div id="BtnEdit">Edit</div>
 <div id="BtnDel">Del</div>

</div>
```

If u do something with image (upload done, delete,....) u just need call `showButton()`